# Why does Lord Ganesha have a mouse as his vehicle?

Tags: puranas, ganesha, symbolism

How did Lord Ganesha get a mouse as his vehicle? Is there a story behind this?

And what does the mouse signify?

Comment: [purely related not duplicate] [Is there an explanation behind the association of certain deities using a particular animal as the deity's vehicle?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/300/93)

Comment: Answer for your question is already given [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/312/130)

Comment: @sv. It applies for you to not to make unnecessary edits! Mythology tag is not at all necessary here! Dont engage in edit war! I ll roll back your edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ganesha came to kill Mushikaasura who is troubling all! In course of war Ganesha broke one of his teeth and thrown on to Mushika to kill, Mushika ran through all Lokas, he found no place to hide and no one who can save him.

In the end Mushaka accepted his defeat and pleaded Ganesha to save his life, Ganesha shown mercy on Mushika and accepted him as his vehicle upon his request!