# The name of Ganesha's mouse

Tags: ganesha

What is the name of Ganesha's mouse? I have heard that it is called Mushaka which is the sanskrit word for mouse (as a species) itself.  Is there any other name mentioned about the specific mouse that was with Ganesha?

Edit: I think my question is quite different from how the mouse became Ganesha's vahana. Even though the answer there might mention nis name as Mushikasura in his Asura form I thought it was not clear whether he retained that name in his form as mouse also. I would like to keep my question open for any other answers. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Lord Ganesha have a mouse as his vehicle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/why-does-lord-ganesha-have-a-mouse-as-his-vehicle)

Answer (score 3):

It is Mushakaraaj.He was singer in heaven in his previous birth(Gandharva),named Kroncha. He once insulted sage Vaamdeva. He then went to Ashram of sage Paraashara and disturbed him. Helpless sage prayed to lord Ganesha. Ganesha,then brought him under his control and took on him as his Vaahana.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Though you have attempted to answer the question on who is vehicle of Ganesha and the name of Ganesha's mouse, we as a site insist on adding some reference for our claims made in answers. Take a look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5212). Please add some reference where this incident of Gandharva insulting Vamadeva is mentioned. You might also like to take a [tour] to understand our Q&A site better.